# Run exe file in bat file using files from another directories

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to run .exe file, which uses another not executable files from different directories.
From command line it works fine.
Could You please help me to find out the syntax how can i make a bat file, which will do it.

Here is the path, that i ran from command line:
C:\Program Files\Test\bin\run.exe -TestPath D:\test1\ -TestPath httpDownloader.lrs D:\test1\Temp -ResultLocation  -ResultCleanName Res1 -Run"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bat file uses comand line syntax so if it works in cmd it should work in .bat

```
"C:\Program Files\Test\bin\run.exe" -TestPath D:\test1\ -TestPath httpDownloader.lrs D:\test1\Temp -ResultLocation -ResultCleanName Res1 -Run
```

Only thing you have to be careful about are spaces in file path!

Comment: when doing so, it gave me an error, that cannot find httpDownloader.lrs,

Comment: i found the problem, i repeat -TestPath :(. Thank you for your help.